# Group only when there are more than 2 similar rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I want to group items only when there are more than 2 rwos matching rule. How can this be done?

E.G: (grouping by `Col`)

```
Col 
----
A
A
B
B
B
```

Should return:

```
Col | count(*)
---------------
A     2
A     2
B     3
```

It only displays B once since there are more than 3 results.

Comment: why A appeared twice and B only once?

Comment: @ajreal did you read the question? _"I want to group items only when there are more than 2 items matching rule."_

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I know how to do it with a self join plus another query but the query will get too long and it's nested in others already

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL - the example output not making sense, i mean is already in the format of grouping

Comment: Why do you want to have A appear twice in the output?

Comment: It's for a sort of forum. And when a user posts more than 3 times in the day, instead of displaying each post it groups all and shows a story like: "Joe posted 5 times".

Comment: I thought the output was clear, added some more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MySQL doesn't have COUNT OVER you need a inline view to get the counts for when the count is less then 3. Then its just a union to a normal count query

```
SELECT counts.col, 
       counts.k 
FROM   test 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col, 
                          COUNT(col) k 
                   FROM   test 
                   GROUP  BY col
                   having count(col)  < 3 ) counts 
         ON test.col = counts.col 

UNION ALL 
SELECT col, 
       COUNT(col) k 
FROM   test 
GROUP  BY col 
HAVING COUNT(col) > 2
```

[See it working here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f12c/10)